# Can hibernate entity relationships support singleton entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Can hibernate entity relationships support references?  What I mean is, I want to maintain a single instance of a certain type of entity while multiple other entities have a reference to it.  So if `C` has a relationship with both `B` and `B2`, can it have only a single instance?  Will `@Singleton` do the job?

```
A -> B
       \
        \
         \
          C
          /
A2 -> B2 /
```

I can see this being tricky because it'll be having to deal with `EAGER`/`LAZY` fetching.  Having a single instance of this entity is very important within my application.

**Update** I should specify that I don't mean a singleton of the class, but of an entity.  So a single instance of the class for each `id`.

Comment: Do you mean hibernate entities ? Or spring components such as controllers, services etc ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky Yes, hibernate

Comment: you can't have singleton hibernate entities, it wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inside a given session**, entities are singletons: Hibernate will always (well, almost always) return the same entity instance, whatever the way you get it : Session.get(), Session.load(), HQL query, Criteria query, etc.

If what you want is a singleton across several sessions, then no, it's impossible (and it wouldn't make sense).